# How to change address of Variables defined in .data section in Assembly x86 64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, memory-address

I have two variables A and B defined in the `.data` section of an assembly program,
Im trying to get A to be equal to the address of B. How can I do this? Is this possible?

```
SECTION .data

A: dq 3.4
B: dq 4.4
```

Comment: You don't, not without crashing. When you define variables (actually **labels**  in assembly), you are just assigning a name for a memory offset within the `.data` section. The offset is fixed by your definition of the variable and it's contents. You can change the **value-at-that-address**, but you can't change the `offset` that your variable (`label`) represents.

Comment: What's the goal ? What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Values of symbols are determined at assembly time, not execution time. So you need to decide what `A` and `B` refer to up front, and then their values are established when you run the assembler and linker. But as M.L. indicates, you must have some other real problem you're trying to solve which you should explain.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the assembler that you are using.
Some assemblers need

```
mov A, offset B
```

Others need

```
mov [A], B
```